# How to connect views to default api urls in Sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I have created a new api using sails `sails generate api tasks`, using the default configuration of sails 0.12.
With Sails awesome blueprints, I can access `localhost:1337/tasks` and see the list of tasks or `localhost:1337/tasks/create?text=yo` to create a new one.

But what I want it to connect these endpoints to an .ejs view.
I tried creating a new folder `tasks` and placing `show.ejs` or `index.ejs` files in it but it's still returning the Json.
Is there a default way to render .ejs files through the default blueprint urls, without creating new routes and controller methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it took me a while to find the answer, so for anyone looking to use sails.js development speed, here is the way to do it:
After generating the api, create a folder inside your views folder (named after your controller). The files in it should be:

```
+ tasks (the folder with the same name as your controller)
    - find.ejs (list of all items)
    - findOne.ejs (view a specific item)
    - create.ejs (after a successful creation)
    - update.ejs (after a successful update)
    - destroy.ejs (after a successful deletion)
```

These files are connected by default to the different api endpoints. So, when you access the url `localhost:1337/tasks` sails will automatically render `tasks/find.ejs`. Same for the other endpoints.

Another point is that each view will have a global variable named `data` that will include the result of the api request (i.e. the records that were fetched / modified).

You can see a small example here: https://github.com/web-development-course/Bootstrap (look at the 'things' api)

I hope it will help you guys